# PHP error - Inserting a user form into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a strange error when I try to submit user-generated data to a database via PHP commands.  When I hit the submit button below, instead of the PHP page running its' function I am presented with a display of the raw code on my browser.  I have a command at the bottom of my HTML page that looks like this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

So that when the user hits the submit button, the PHP file insert.php (detailed below) is called to input the answers onto a database, separating each answer into it's own field.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_errno();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Serif, Width, Height, Spacing, Weight)
VALUES
('$_POST[answer]','$_POST[answer]','$_POST[answer]','$_POST[answer]','$_POST[answer]','$_POST[answer]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Right now, the questions are in a  and not a  (is there a functional difference in this case?).  They look like:

```
<form class="testAns" id="widthAns">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="skinny">-25%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="skinny">-10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="fat">+10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="fat">+25%
</form>

<form class="testAns" id="spaceAns">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="small">-25%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="small">-10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="wide">+10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="wide">+25%
</form>

<form class="testAns" id="weightAns">
<input type="radio" name="wanswer" value="light">-25%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="light">-10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="heavy">+10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="heavy">+25%
</form>


<form method="post" action="insert.php" class="testAns" id="heightAns">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="short">-25%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="short">-10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="tall">+10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="tall">+25%
</form>
```

The important part is for the "value" associated with each button to be logged into the database.  For example, if a user selects "+10%" I want be able to log the word "heavy".And then there are two text input fields:

```
<form id="intro">
City: <input type="text" name="answer"><br>
Why you are using this tool:<input type="text" name="answer">
</form>
```

So for these text fields I need the user input logged as the answer.

Comment: You really needto escape your input to avoid SQL injecions. Have a look at *Prepared Statements*

Comment: Have you any web-server installed? And does it configured properly? I mean does it handle '.php' extension and process it through interpreter?

Comment: Do you have a webserver installed? Raw php code sounds like you dont have a server running.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: I'm working off of the DreamHost server so it should handle .php just fine.  I got that to work, but now it seems that none of my answers are logged correctly, they just show up blank in the data table.

Do I need to have 'answer' in '$_POST[answer]' be a unique value for each question?  I currently have them in order that they would be answered by a user

Comment: check if the insert.php is in the same directory as your HTML file otherwise double check your path......

Comment: Can you include in your post your input fields?

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the PHP thing fixed.

Now you need to fill your form with data. This:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

sends only the submit value. You need to add input fields inside that form tag, otherwise, nothing else will get sent. So, since you're sending an answer array, you should add those (adding them as text fields, as an example):

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    etc...
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And make sure you filter all user inputs before writing anything into the database, as otherwise my buddy [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) might come to visit you.

Comment: That sneaky Bobby Tables.  Each <input> has a "value" set within it that I want logged as the answer once a submit button is pressed.  How would I make sure that only the "value" is entered into the database?

For example, a possible answer would be: 

<input type="radio" name="answer" value="wide">+10%

The "+10%" is what the user will click on, but I want log the value "wide".

Comment: No worries, it's the value that gets sent via POST, not the string after the input. It should work fine, just make sure the inputs are inside the form.

Comment: Can I add this action to each individual form and have it submit in a similar manner? Right now, each question is in its own form and if I add action="insert.php" to each form I'm worried that it will treat the data separately.  Or is there a way to log only the user's answers?  Is that what the [] delineates on your code, that the answer that the user clicks will be inserted?

Comment: If you're using AJAX, then it's ok to use multiple forms, however, with regular form, you should wrap all the questions inside one, and use the answers array (that's why []) to fetch all data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your **XAMPP Control Panel** that *Apache* and *MySQL* are running. Then check if your input fields are inside the `<form action='insert.php' method='POST'> input fields </form>`

Your HTML code would look like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action='insert.php' method='POST'>

<table>
<tr><td>Width: </td><td>
<input type="radio" name="width" value="skinny">-25%
<input type="radio" name="width" value="skinny">-10%
<input type="radio" name="width" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="width" value="fat">+10%
<input type="radio" name="width" value="fat">+25%
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Spacing: </td><td>    
<input type="radio" name="spacing" value="small">-25%
<input type="radio" name="spacing" value="small">-10%
<input type="radio" name="spacing" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="spacing" value="wide">+10%
<input type="radio" name="spacing" value="wide">+25%
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Weight: </td><td>
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="light">-25%
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="light">-10%
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="heavy">+10%
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="heavy">+25%
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Height: </td><td>    
<input type="radio" name="height" value="short">-25%
<input type="radio" name="height" value="short">-10%
<input type="radio" name="height" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="height" value="tall">+10%
<input type="radio" name="height" value="tall">+25%
</td></tr>

<tr><td>City: </td><td><input type="text" name="city"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Why you are using this tool: </td><td><input type="text" name="tool"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit'></td></tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What are you using in creating your php files? Dreamweaver? Notepad? Try this: *SAVE AS* your file, **Save As Type: All Files** and name it **insert.php**.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","YourUsername","YourPassword(if any)","NameOfYourDatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_errno();
  }

$width=$_POST['width'];
$spacing=$_POST['spacing'];
$weight=$_POST['weight'];
$height=$_POST['height'];
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['city']);
$tool=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['tool']);

/* REAL ESCAPE STRING WOULD PREVENT A BIT OF SQL INJECTION */

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Serif, Width, Height, Spacing, Weight)
VALUES
('$city','$tool','$width','$height','$spacing','$weight')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I'm using radio buttons as my mode of selection, does that affect the <tr><td> tags?  I'm creating my php files using Coda 2.

Comment: @user3452790 - Can you provide us your HTML code/radio buttons? And the <tr><td> is for the table. No need to worry about it.

Comment: What is your current problem?

Comment: The page that I go to reads: 
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'aarpet6'@'william-samuel.dreamhost.com' (using password: YES) in /home/aarpet6/capstone.aaronpetrik.com/insert.php on line 4
1 record added

Comment: Hey. Wait. Did you change your mysqli_connect according to your PhpMyAdmin? And you should provide five radio buttons on each five questions, right?

Comment: I definitely did not change any settings on PhpMyAdmin yet, I'll go check that out now.  And there will be five radio buttons for four questions, the other two questions are text fields.  Are those treated differently?

Comment: @user3452790 - Of course. Let me change my answer for you then. What are the four questions that have radio buttons? And what are the choices? Then what are the other two fields that require text fields? Give me also the name of your PhpMyAdmin's username, password (if any), and name of database. And name of your table

Comment: Can I send you an email?  It's too much info for the comment box's character max

Comment: Why don't you include it in your post?

Comment: I've included all of the questions in my post.  The username and password is pretty sensitive information, don't think I want to put that in public.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll try that out in just a second. Each of the questions will also have a visual element that I've yet to create.  Basically, every question will have an associated image that changes with an onclick function.  The image is how the user decides their preference.  Will having the <form> tag around these images affect their functionality?

Comment: @user3452790 You should only provide one <form> for them. You should try <div> instead of another <form> if you want to design your page.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks for all your help Logan!  You've got some good karma coming your way.

Comment: @user3452790 Why don't you try putting them into table. See my updated html answer